What should I apply to get $8$ as my answer in $\frac{x^2-16}{x-4}$?
What should I apply to get $8$ as my answer in $\dfrac{x^2-16}{x-4}$?
I equate it with $8$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^2-16}{x-4} &= 8 \\
&\iff (x^2-16)=8(x-4) \\
&\iff x^2-16=8x-32 \\
&\iff x^2-8x+16 = 0 \\
&\iff x^2-4x-4x+16 = 0 \\
&\iff x(x-4)-4(x-4) = 0 \\
&\iff (x-4)(x-4) = 0 \\
&\iff x-4=0 \\
&\iff x=+4. \\
\end{align}$$
This means that, if I apply $4$ to $x$, then the answer will be $8$, right? Am I wrong?
Applying $4$ to $x$ yields:
$$\frac{4^2-16}{4-4}= \frac{0}{0}= \text{undefined}.$$
All I need is to clear up confusion.

Please edit for clarity.  Avoid run on "equations" ...writing $a=b=c$ really, really ought to imply that $a=c$ but not here.  you write things like $x^2-16=8x-32=x^2-8x+16$ which is just confusing.

here is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Your first step is not an equivalence because the original problem is not defined at $x=4$ while the transformed problem is well defined at $x=4$.  There is no value for $x$ that will make $\frac {x^2-16}{x-4}=8$.  If you plot the graph of $\frac {x^2-16}{x-4}=y$ carefully you will get the line $y=x+4$ with a hole at $x=4,y=8$.

What you may notice is that $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-16}{x-4}=\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{x-4}=x+4$$
Your equation now becomes $x+4=8$, which happens when $x=4$. The reason this does not work for the original equation, however, is that at $x=4,\space x-4=0$, and you can't just cancel out zeros like any other number. What you need to do is to take the limit as $x$ approaches $4$. $$f(4)=8\text{ is false,  } \lim_{x\rightarrow4}{f(x)=8\text{ is true.}}$$
